# Displaying marker in Google map on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, onclick

I have the following script:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization">
</script>
<script>
   var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'geojson';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
    window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
      var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
      });
    }
  }

</script>
```

As it is visible that the script.src is a file called 'geojson'
I am developing a browser application where the user clicks on a year from a dropdown menu. The back end scripts gets executed and it generates a new geojson file which includes new coordinates in geojson format. however these positions are not visible in the current map until I reload the page. Is it possible to reload the map 1 or 2 seconds after the script execution or is there some way to send the data back through ajax so that the map detects the new positions and displays them. Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did this by calling this function initialize() on the click event. So that every time a user clicks on the button this function is called and now the script.src refers to the new geojson file formed by the script.